# Halmos: Proving that $Ring(E \cap A) \cup Ring(E) - A$ is closed under differences.

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Retyped the question so it is self-contained

Theorem E of Halmos's Measure Theory shows that: If E is any class of set and A is any subset of X, then $Ring(E) \cap A = Ring(E \cap A)$. To show this is true he constructs the set **C** defined as $B \cup (K-A)$ with $B \in Ring(E \cap A)$ and $K \in Ring(E)$. The text says that it is easy to verify that this set is a ring, but I can't find a way to show that A-B is in **C** given that A,B are in **C**. Please Help!